# Display website in I-frame via post method and pass header and body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load a website in an I-frame. this is the first time I have to call the post method and pass a header and body.
This is my attempt with ajax.

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'example.com',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    FirstName: "john doe"
                },
                headers: {
                    Token: "token"
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.info(data);
                    $("#output_iframe_id").attr('src', "/")
                    $("#output_iframe_id").contents().find('html').html(data);
                }
            });
```

I get a CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44349/archive/statements' from origin 'https://localhost:44346' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Update:
I used HttpClient and was able to pass the needed header and body. the site loads in the i-frame. However, the site does not behave correctly. I loose session data on additional calls to the server.

```
string jsonString = GetJsonString(req);
string url = example.com;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "token");
         var clientRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
         {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
          };

         var Res = await client.PostAsync(url, clientRequest.Content);
         ViewBag.Statements = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }

Usage:
   <div>
       <iframe srcdoc="@ViewBag.Statements"></iframe>
   </div>
```

Comment: Then read the CORS error and do what it tells you.

Comment: I am trying to get this setup using local host. from what I have read about the CORS error is I have to configure IIS for it.

Comment: i found some articles on adding <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Origin, Content-Type"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/> but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the ajax call working. I ended up adding a test page within the application itself and below is the working ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'example.com',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    FirstName: "john doe"
                },
                headers: {
                    Token: "token"
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output_iframe_id").contents().find('html').html(data);
                }
            });
```

AS for the HTTPClient call. I found a few articles stating that HTTPClient doesn't return all HTML so I ended up focusing on the ajax call.